# Images disappearing when importing Bootstrap stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page on my site that when I hover over one of the pictures, an overlay appears with a caption for the image. Here's the code for one of these images:

```
<div id="content">
            <div class="mosaic-block fade">
                <a target ="_blank" href = "files/file1.pdf" class="mosaic-overlay">
                    <div class="details">
                        <h4>Form #1</h4>
                        <p>Permission Slip</p>
                        </div>
                </a>
                <div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="img/thumb1.jpg"/></div>
            </div>
```

With these stylesheets/scripts linked in my header, the images and overlays work

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mosaic.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../events/eventInfoStyle.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../events/headbar.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../events/header.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mosaic.1.0.1.js"></script>
```

But when I add the bootstrap ones, the images no longer appear. Here are the bootstrap ones I'm adding.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

What is causing the images to not appear with Bootstrap added in?
Here's the rest of my CSS:

MAIN.CSS:

```
    .nav{
  background-color:white;

 }
.affix{
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.nav a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;


}

.nav li {
  display: inline;

}

.jumbotron {
  margin-top:5px;

  height: 700px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #56A0D3;
  background-image: url('wvlogo.png');

}

.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  top:100px;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 48px;  
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align:center;


}

.jumbotron p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.learn-more {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;

}

.learn-more h3 {
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.learn-more a {
  color: #00b0ff;
}

.announcements{
    background-color:#efefef;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
}
.announcements h2{
    color:#393c3d;
    font-size:24px;
    }
.announcements p{
    font-size:15px;
    color:rgb(0, 32, 96);
    margin-bottom:13px;
    text-align:center;
    height:150px;
    padding:30px;
    border-radius:25px;
    background-color: #56A0D3;
}


.myStatsLogin{
  background-color:#56A0D3;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:5px;
  border-radius:25px;
  width:300px;
  text-align:center;
  margin:auto;
  color: rgb(0,32,96);
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 7px 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.carousel-announcement{
  height:200px;
  color:rgb(0,32,96);
  font-size:32px;
  background-color:#56A0D3;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:20px;  
  padding-left:100px;
  padding-right:100px;
}

.section-title h1{
  font-size:48px;
  margin:0px;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:underline;
  color: rgb(0,32,96);
  background-color:#56A0D3;
}
EVENTINFOSTYLE.CSS:
h1{



    color:#002060;
     font-size: 40px;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 7px 5px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      background-color:#56A0D3;
      border-radius:25px;
      border:solid 3px rgb(0,32,96);
    margin:0;

    margin-top:1em;

}



form{

    width:50%;

    position:relative;

    display:inline-block;

}

body{

    background-color:#00007f;

     background: linear-gradient(#B4D8E7, #00005f);
     /*background-repeat:no-repeat;
     height:100%;*/

     text-align:center;

}

.sideImage{

    float:right;

    width:40%;

    display:inline-block;

}

img{

    position:relative;

    width:100%;

}

.announcment{

    margin: 0 auto;

    background-color: rgba(0,32,96,.85);
    border-radius:15px;

    padding: 2em;

    display: block;

    position: relative;

    text-align: left;

}

.announcment h1{

    color: white;

    font-family: "Calisto MT", "Bookman Old Style", Bookman, "Goudy Old Style", Garamond, "Hoefler Text", "Bitstream Charter", Georgia, serif;

    font-style: italic;

    font-size: 3em;

    text-shadow:2px 2px #000;

    margin-top: 0;

    text-align: center;

}

.announcment h2{

    color: white;

    font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;

    font-size: x-large;

    text-shadow:2px 2px #000;

}

.announcment p{

    color: white;

    font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;

    font-size: large;

    text-shadow:2px 2px #000;

}



.announcment li{

    color: white;

    font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;

    font-size: large;

    text-shadow:2px 2px #000;

}

.announcmentWrapper{

    margin: 0 auto;

    margin-bottom:2em;

    margin-top:2em;

    padding: 1em;

    width: 70%;

    background-color: #56A0D3;
    border-radius:25px ;

    position: relative;

    display: inline-block;

}



hr.experiencehr {

    border: 0;

    height: 1px;

    background: #3498db;

    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,50,96,.85), #3498db, rgba(0,50,96,.85)); 

    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,50,96,.85), #3498db, rgba(0,50,96,.85)); 

    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,50,96,.85), #3498db, rgba(0,50,96,.85)); 

    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,50,96,.85), #3498db, rgba(0,50,96,.85)); 

}

li{

    line-height: 0em;

}

a:link{

    color:#eee;

}

a:visited{

    color:#ccc;

}

HEADBAR.CSS:
.signup{

    position:relative;

    border-left:1px solid black;

    color:white;

    float:right;

    padding: 0.5em;

    margin:0.2em;

    font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;

    cursor:pointer;

    z-index:100;

}

.headbar{

    position:fixed;

    background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #005fbf 5%, #003f7f 100%);    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #005fbf), color-stop(1, #003f7f) );

    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #005fbf 5%, #003f7f 100% );

    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#005fbf", endColorstr="#003f7f");  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#005fbf,003f7f);

    width:100%;

    z-index:9999;

    overflow:hidden;

    height:2.5em;

}

body{

    margin:0;

}
```

Comment: Most probably bootstrap's css is overriding your custom css. Please post your css codes too here.

Comment: I have tried putting my css at the end, putting bootstrap's after mine, and trying it without my css, but whenever bootstrap is there the images don't show up. And even if it was somehow overriding how would that cause images to not show up?

Comment: Please post your css and I'll check it out.

Comment: Ok updated the post, thanks

Comment: This question will be answerd fast if you upload your code online ie codepen , or fiddle it http://codepen.io

Comment: The issue with using one of those is that my full code links to other files/images, and I'm connecting to bootstrap with maxcdn

Answer (score 2):

Your `.fade` class is also a bootstrap class. rename it `my-fade` and see if that does it.

Comment: That resulted in an outline of the image showing up, but no image

Comment: did you change it in your js pages too?